# GStreamer udpsrc works with gst-launch but not in app (OSX)

Tags: macos, udp, streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I successfully streamed my webcam's image with GStreamer using gst-launch this way :

SERVER

```
./gst-launch-1.0 -v -m autovideosrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGRA ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc pass=qual quantizer=20 tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port=7480
```

CLIENT

```
./gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=7480 ! "application/x-rtp, payload=127" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! glimagesink
```

Now I try to reproduce the client side in my app using this pipeline (I don't post the code as I made an Objective-C wrapper around my pipeline and elements) :

1. udpsrc with caps:`"application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=127,encoding-name=H264"`
2. rtph264depay
3. decodebin
4. glimagesink (for testing) or a custom appsink (in pull-mode) that converts image to CVPixelBufferRef (tested: it works with videotestsrc / uridecodebin / etc.)

It doesn't work, even if the state messages of the pipeline look quite 'normal'. I have messages in the console concerning `SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22` but I have them too when working with the command line.
I'm asking myself what's under gst-launch that I'm missing. I couldn't find any example on the web on udpsrc based pipeline.

My questions are :

- Does anybody knows what's actually happening when we launch gst-launch or a way to know what's actually happening?
- Are there some examples of working pipelines in code with udpsrc?

---

**EDIT**

---

Here is the image of my pipeline. As you can see, GstDecodeBin element doesn't create a src pad, as it's not receiving - or treating - anything (I set a 'timeout' property to 10 seconds on the udpsrc element, that is thrown). **Could it be an OSX sandboxing problem?**

Now my pipeline looks like this:

1. udpsrc
2. queue
3. h264 depay
4. decode bin
5. video converter
6. caps filter
7. appsink / glimagesink

[image: pipeline]

Tested with the method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972337/objective-c-sockets-cant-correctly-receive-string-in-udp-message) question, the app does actually receive something on this port.

Comment: How do you transmit SPS/PPS? I think regular RTP expects this data to be out-of-band. If you want it to be in-band I think you need to specify this in the rtp pay-loader. The decoder won't be able to decode any data and therefore won't have any pads. Eventually in your test you started the decoder before the encoder and perhaps the encoder will send SPS/PPS once before the first frame. If the decoder misses that data it will wait for it indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry: I don't know what is SPS/PPS... It looks like udpsrc element itself doesn't "accept" my data. I looked into the gst-launch program source, but nothing... I send data using gst-launch command line I published in my question, before any attempt to get it via the app...

Comment: SPS and PPS are H.264 codec configuration data, crucial for decoders to decode the bitstream. Try adding `h264parse config-interval=1`after `x264enc`.

Comment: If that doesn't help also try `option-string=\"repeat-headers=1\"`as option for the `x264enc`.

Comment: No way, same thing : it looks like I'm not receiving anything when using udpsrc element in my program. I tried to create the GSocket manually with no results. Could it be that udpsrc element put itslef in multicast mode automatically? I have this message: *GLib-GObject-WARNING **: The property GstUDPSrc:multicast-group is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found why it wasn't receiving anything: **GstUdpSrc element must be in** `GST_STATE_NULL` **to be assigned a port to listen to**, or it will listen to the default port (5004) silently.

Everything works fine now.

Setting the environment variable GST_DEBUG to udpsrc:5 helped a lot, for information.

Comment: Mark your answer as answer then.